# Redmine text formatting per-project

Tags: text, formatting, markdown, redmine, textile

I want to set different text formatters in different Redmine projects. E.g. users of one project prefer textile, users of the other - markdown. But Redmine has single global setting for `text formatter`.

Currently we use Redmine 2.1.2

Comment: BTW, I'm not the first to ask it from Redmine: http://www.redmine.org/issues/4015

Comment: And why do you think you will get an answer to a non code-related question on StackOverflow when there are already existing issues on the appropriate bug tracker?

Comment: I think the one who can code in ruby is able to solve it by a couple of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Redmine does not have such feature out of the box, but you can install a plugin that will let you have per-project based formatting.

One such plugin is this:
https://github.com/a-ono/redmine_per_project_formatting

To install it:

1. Navigate to your redmine root folder like /opt/redmine
2. Download and unpack, or git clone:

   git clone https://github.com/a-ono/redmine_per_project_formatting.git plugins/redmine_per_project_formatting
3. Execute migration:

   bundle exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
4. Start or restart your Redmine